# how can extract snapshots in different times from gromacs trajectory with python?

Tags: python

I have performed md simulation with gromacs, now I want to extract pdb files from trajectory by this command gmx trjconv -f traj.xtc -s traj.tpr -o file.pdb -dump 100
by this command, I can get pdb at 100 psecond, but I need 1000 snapshots, so the next time would be -dump 110, so each time, will add 10 to the number. How can I do it in automatic way by python?

gmx trjconv -f traj.xtc -s traj.tpr -o 100.pdb -dump 100

gmx trjconv -f traj.xtc -s traj.tpr -o 110.pdb -dump 110

gmx trjconv -f traj.xtc -s traj.tpr -o 120.pdb -dump 120

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
gmx trjconv -b 100 -dt 10 -f trajectory.{trr|xtc} -s trajectory.tpr
```

to extract those frames to a separate trajectory and then extract all frames as separate files with `-sep`.